# opposite of spark dataframe `withColumn` method?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to be able to chain a transformation on my `DataFrame` that drops a column, rather than assigning the `DataFrame` to a variable (i.e. `df.drop()`).  If I wanted to add a column, I could simply call `df.withColumn()`.  What is the way to drop a column in an in-line chain of transformations?

Comment: Can you add an example where `drop` does not work as the opposite of `withColumn`? You should be able to use it inside a chain of tranformations.

Comment: lol yea ok that works

Answer (score 0):

For the entire example use this as baseline:

```
val testVariable = 10
var finalDF = spark.sql("'test' as test_column")

val iDF = spark.sql("select 'John Smith' as Name, cast('10' as integer) as Age, 'Illinois' as State")
val iDF2 = spark.sql("select 'Jane Doe' as Name, cast('40' as integer) as Age, 'Iowa' as State")
val iDF3 = spark.sql("select 'Blobby' as Name, cast('150' as integer) as Age, 'Non-US' as State")
val nameDF = iDF.unionAll(iDF2).unionAll(iDF3)
```

1 Conditional Drop
If you want to only drop on certain outputs and these are known outputs, you can build out conditional loops to check if the iterator needs to be dropped or not. In this case if the test variable exceeds 4 it will drop the name column, else it adds a new column.

```
finalDF = if (testVariable>=5) {
  nameDF.drop("Name")
} else {
  nameDF.withColumn("Cooler_Name", lit("Cool_Name")
}

finalDF.printSchema
```

2 Programmatically build the select statement. Baseline the select expression statement takes in independent strings and build them into commands that can be read by Spark. In the case below we know we have a test for drop but we do know what columns might be dropped. In this case if a column gets a test values that does not equal 1 we do not include the value in out command array. When we run the command array against the select expression on the table, those columns are dropped.

```
val columnNames = nameDF.columns
val arrayTestOutput = Array(1,0,1)
var iteratorArray = 1
var commandArray = Array("")
while(iteratorArray <= columnNames.length) {
  if (arrayTestOutput(iteratorArray-1) == 1) {
    if (iteratorArray == 1) {
      commandArray = columnNames(iteratorArray-1)
    } else {
      commandArray = commandArray ++ columnNames(iteratorArray-1)
    }
  }
  iteratorArray = iteratorArray + 1
}
finalDF=nameDF.selectExpr(commandArray:_*)
finalDF.printSchema
```

Comment: really involved, but i'm just looking for a drop-in replacement i.e. `dataFrame.withoutColumn(...`

Comment: Are you looking for something like nameDF.selectExpr("*", "length(Name) as Length_Name").drop("Name").withColumn("Name",lit("No_Name"))?

Comment: Not need "FROM t" clause in the `spark.sql()` method?

Comment: @peter it will internally generate the values, it's a cheap and cheesy way of generating test data of the appropriate structure without running a series of struct commands.

Comment: @afeldman, in this case, the "cheap and cheesy way" seems `Seq(("John Smith", 10, "Illinois")).toDF("Name","Age","State")`

Comment: @PeterKrauss If you put 'em in Seq arrays should cut out the union as well. The issue with Spark is the same with R, there are multiple ways to do everything. I have just gotten into the habit for using Spark.sql to build my empty variable data frames that need to get overwritten 'var interimDF = spark.sql("select 'foo' as bar")', and just want to stay consistent. To anyone else reading my answer if you need to create multiple rows by hand please use the Array(Seq()).toDF() not my method.